# BBEdit "Find" dialog vs. CR and LF

Tags: bbedit

In BBEdit (v11.6), when I search for the "\r" character in a txt file previoulsy saved as "Unix (LF)" from the "Save as..." dialog, the result is the end of each individual line of the file.

Why?

The BBEdit hex dump correctly shows that no CR (OD) chars are present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [11.6 release notes](http://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/current_notes.html):

> BBEdit now uses the line feed (ASCII decimal 10) as line breaks in its internal representation for text in open documents, instead of the carriage return (ASCII decimal 13) that was the standard Mac format for many years. This (theoretically) reduces the time required to open documents, since in the normal case, no conversion is necessary; it also eliminates conversion logic when copying and pasting text, since LF-delimited text is also the standard interchange format on the Clipboard.
>
> As before, you may use \n and \r interchangeably in search strings and Grep patterns. (The latter usage is for compatibility with old versions of BBEdit.)